# Faces are like blobs - what is wrong?

Tags: faces

I downloaded an .obj-file, and imported it into Blender 2.81, and I get some smooth surfaces - all is good, but I would like to see the flat version, so I go to `Object Mode`, `Object`, `Shade Flatten` - all is still fine.

I then find out I have a lot of duplicates, which I remove from `Edit Mode`, `Mesh`, `Clean Up`, `By Distance`.

If I then try to smooth it again, I get these weird blobs:
[image: Weird blobs on faces]

I tried editing the Object Data Property for `Normals`, `Auto Smooth`, but that makes no difference from 0 to 180 degrees.

When I click on the individual vertices it looks fine by showing the nearby vertices they are connected to.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you try clearing the "custom split data" in the object data properties ? It is in a foldout under the normals auto-smooth field

Comment: This indeed does the trick. And now ``Auto Smooth`` actually does something :D